# textMateRules for parameters and parameter usages syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

i have this setting for highligting parameter declarations in JS

```json
{
   "name": "Parameter",
   "scope": "variable.parameter",
   "settings": {
       "foreground": "#BC84FF"
   }
}
```

it works fine, but the usages of the parameters are not highlighted with the setting, but with that of variables. My question is: how can define the scope that also highlights the parameter usages the same as parameter declarations

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: No, i'm still search for a solution :-). There still isn't no specific scope for parameter usages within a JS function.

Comment: I just added a feature request, feel free to argument https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165483